# Need help in clearTImeout

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

**Ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var stopTime =0;
 var scoreCheck =  function ()
    {
      $.ajax({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1/ProgVsProg/main/checkScoreRoundOne',
      success:function(output){
        if(output !='Instruction'){
       console.log(output);
                clearTimeout(scoreCheck);
            }
        else 
            console.log(output);
            stopTime = setTimeout(scoreCheck, 1000);  
    }
  });
}
 stopTime = setTimeout(scoreCheck,1000);
 </script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function checkScoreRoundOne(){
    $id = $this->session->userdata('userID');
    $battleID = $this->lawmodel->getBattle($id);
    foreach($battleID as $row){
        $Rscore = $row->requestedScore;
        $Cscore = $row->challengerScore;
          if($Cscore == '1'){
        $rID = $this->lawmodel->getID($row->challengerID);
          foreach($rID as $row){
          echo $row->username."Got the correct answer"; 
             }
           }
          else if($Rscore == '1'){
           $cID =$this->lawmodel->getID($row->requestedID);
           foreach($cID as $row){
                echo $row->username."Got the correct answer";
            }
        }
            else 
                echo "Instruction";

        }
}
```

Im confused in the code above

- In ajax, why when the output !='Instruction' it will display  "Instruction" and when the output == 'Instruction' it will display $row->username got the correct answer.
- And how can i stop the setTimeout when the Cscore == 1 or Rscore ==1? 
  I think cleartimeout will not just stop the setTimeout..

Plss help...Im new in ajax..
Im using codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

About the clearTimeout:

```
clearTimeout(stopTime);
```